# Получение полигона точек по адресу с помощью Yandex API Maps

Tags: c#, yandex-maps-api

в документации к Yandex API Maps существуют примеры работы с полигонами:

```
// Создаем многоугольник в виде прямоугольника.
    var polygon = new ymaps.Polygon([
        [
            [30, 40],
            [30, 50],
            [40, 50],
            [40, 40],
            [30, 40]
        ]
    ]);
    // Добавляем многоугольник на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(polygon);
```

Вопрос: существует ли возможность получения списка полигонов по входным данным в виде центра координат нужного объекта, например: Московская область.
На входе: координаты центра
На выходе: полигон в виде точек

Comment: Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin - вопрос переформулирован

Comment: т.е., вас устроит ответ «да, существует/нет, не существует». в принципе, ничего страшного. разве что это «неформат» для данного сайта.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin как мне кажется, это логично, что если это возможно, то с помощью чего это делается или Вам нужно чтобы я явно это указал в вопросе?

Answer (score 1):

В API есть метод [geoQuery.searchContaining()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult.html#method_detail__searchContaining), с помощью которого можно узнать, к границах какого объекта находится адрес (или координаты). [Пример от Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones).

Получить координаты вершин найденного объекта можно с помощью [geoObject.geometry.getCoordinates()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/IPolygonGeometryAccess.html#method_detail__getCoordinates)

Если нужно вернуть геометрию именно регионов России, поставьте [модуль Регионы](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions.html#regions__geojson-obj).